# Node.js function visibility across files/modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I import an another javascript file  into the main file.  That imported file
exports a single function named create_data. I call that function  from
several function in the main module and all works fine.  But the other way
around seems  not to work because none of the function declared in the main
module is visible inside the imported function create_data.
It looks like I have an understanding problem about visibility of function across
different files/modules. Searched the Node docs and Internet but could not find
any explanation; all files are standard javascript files.

Comment: How do you import and export from the main file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like a problem with circular dependencies and order of evaluation? But we can only guess.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.